# svelte:window innerWidth undefined in the first load

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have this component to check device size

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { deviceSize } from "$lib/stores";

    let innerWidth;

    
    $: if (innerWidth >= 1652) {
        $deviceSize = {
            xl: true,
            lg: false,
            md: false,
            dsm: false,
            sm: false,
        };
    } else if (innerWidth >= 1240 && innerWidth < 1652) {
        $deviceSize = {
            xl: false,
            lg: true,
            md: false,
            dsm: false,
            sm: false,
        };
    } else if (innerWidth >= 794 && innerWidth < 1240) {
        $deviceSize = {
            xl: false,
            lg: false,
            md: true,
            dsm: false,
            sm: false,
        };
    } else if (innerWidth >= 640 && innerWidth < 794) {
        $deviceSize = {
            xl: false,
            lg: false,
            md: false,
            dsm: true,
            sm: false,
        };
    } else {
        $deviceSize = {
            xl: false,
            lg: false,
            md: false,
            dsm: false,
            sm: true,
        };
    }
    $: console.log(innerWidth);
</script>

<svelte:window bind:innerWidth />
```

and a App Component like this

<App.svelte>

```
<script>   
const { lg, xl } = $deviceSize;
$: isDesktop = xl || lg;
</script>

{#if isDesktop}
<DesktopComponent/>
{/if}

{#if !isDesktop}
<MobileComponent/>
{/if}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iNXn.png)

My problem is innerWidth always is undefined in the initial load. So isDesktop = false, then always render MobileComponent even when I use desktop. Please help me fix this.

I tried to set default value for `deviceSize` store, but not work as I want, it's always render as the defauft condition for whatever I use (PC, mobile).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received a solution from @vnphanquang in Discord Svelte Vietnam https://discord.com/channels/1066621936546877450/1194881202331598909

The problem is that I defined `const { lg, xl } = $deviceSize;`, it's `const` so can't update new data. The solution is changing it to `$: ({ lg, xl } = $deviceSize);`

Answer (score 0):

According to [the svelte docs](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte-components#:%7E:text=Reactive%20statements%20run%20after%20other%20script%20code%20and%20before%20the%20component%20markup%20is%20rendered%2C):

> Reactive statements run after other script code and before the component markup is rendered

Meaning your if-else block runs once before the `svelte:window` binding is created, at which point `innerWidth` is undefined.

To avoid that, you can initialize `innerWidth` to the right value, e.g. replace

```js
let innerWidth;
```

with

```js
let innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
```

That said, you'll probably make your life easier by using [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_media_queries/Using_media_queries) to show and hide markup based on the screen size, rather than JavaScript.

Comment: I changed to let innerWidth = window.innerWidth;, but it did not work. Otherwise, if I initialize `innerWidth` with a default value like `innerWidth = 1500`, it will always render DesktopComponent even when I use mobile

Comment: Is the component that sets the `deviceSize` being initialized before the `App` component?